# How to read multi-char keysyms with getchar?

Tags: c, unix, terminal, io

I am using a terminal in raw mode and a problem is that some key presses return one int and others return two. For example, getchar() of 'A' is 65, but if the user presses Alt-D then getchar() returns 27 and 100. Function keys can even return three codes. For example, 'F4' generates 27 79 83 on my terminal. So, the multi-byte sequences always start with 27, but thereafter might be one or two characters.

This is a problem because if I stop reading after one character, then a miscellaneous code is left in the buffer, so the next time my input loop starts again, then it reads it and gets an erroneous value. So, for example, in the case above if the user presses F4, then 83 will be left over in the buffer and will later get read as the character 'S'.

On the other hand if I try to read three characters, then the input loop will hang if the escape sequence only has two characters because getchar() is a blocking call.

What I need is to call getchar() and if I get an escape (27), then I need some way to read all the characters remaining in the buffer and not block while doing so.

Answer (score 2):

You simply have to check what `getchar` returns. If it's `27` then you need to read at least one more character. Use `getchar` to read it as well, and *again* check what it returned to know if you need to read yet one more time.

---

Something like

```
int ch;  // The getchar function returns an int (important for EOF check)

if ((ch = getchar()) == 27)
{
    // Escape read, there's more characters to read
    if ((ch = getchar()) == 79)
    {
        // It's a function key, there's one more characters to read
        ch = getchar();

        // Check which function key was input
        switch (ch)
       {
       case 83:
           // F4...
           break;

        //...

        default:
            // Unknown key...
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Not a function key, perhaps Alt-D?
        if (ch == 100)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
else
{
    // Not escape, a normal key...
}
```

Comment: getchar blocks, so my program will hang if I do this

Comment: @TylerDurden Remember to ***check*** the result of the ***previous*** call to `getchar` before calling `getchar` again. It's a set of nested `if` statements simply.

Comment: I have no way of knowing whether a particular escape sequence has 2 or 3 characters.

Comment: @TylerDurden What each key should generate for codes should be well documented and available from all over the Internet.